# Is there an equivielent of Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.RangeSelector for WinUI3?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3

I'm learning XAML for a WinUI3 / C# desktop app and i have found a control for a range selection slider with two handles in the UWP toolkit, but i don't know if/how to implement that namespace in a native WinUI3 project.  I'd prefer a proper new implementation if possible, but i don't know if there is something similar?  My best searches are coming up empty.

```
<Page ...
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"/>

<controls:RangeSelector x:Name="RangeSelectorControl"
    Minimum="10"
    Maximum="100"
    StepFrequency="2">
</controls:RangeSelector>
```

Comment: You can download WinUI 3 Controls Gallery from MS Store

Comment: @McNets Thankyou, yes, i have that, but it doesn't have a multipoint selector like the rangeselector from the UWP toolkit that i can find :(

Comment: You can find actual controls [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the WinUI 3 version of the toolkit: CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Input

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/winui/7.1.2/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Input/RangeSelector

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Input/

Comment: Kevin, this was exactly what i was looking for, works a treat :)